# monetizing APIs in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager

For my use case, I need to enable monetization feature in wso2am 4.0.0. the solution which is explained in [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-monetization/monetizing-an-api/) limits us to use stripe as a billing engine ( other mentioned solution i.e. implementing Monetization interface is difficult!!). Stripe is not free and open source. Has anyone found any other solution for handling monetization?

Comment: if implementing monetization interface is not difficult. I would appreciate any guid for implementing it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.